# Do not start bluetooth automaticaly. How to do that?

Tags: bluetooth, autostart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I deactivate Bluetooth on system startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/how-can-i-deactivate-bluetooth-on-system-startup)

I want that my bluetooth by defautl be turned off. How can I do that? Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To deactivate blueooth at startup you can add `rfkill block bluetooth` in the file */etc/rc.local*.
And you can activate bluetooth via the bluetooth applet, if you want.

Comment: This still worked well on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You need some more on Ubuntu 15.10: http://askubuntu.com/a/696226/34298

Answer (score 0):

I found with my laptop that there was an option in the BIOS (typically hit Del when your computer is starting.)