# rfkill block bluetooth disables wifi too?

Tags: wireless, dell, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deactivate Bluetooth on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/deactivate-bluetooth-on-startup)

I have a Dell N4110 system. I want to disable bluetooth on the system and hence I used the command `sudo rfkill block bluetooth`. But when I checked the list, I see that my wifi has been hard blocked too.

Moreover, I noticed that the index for the devices on `rfkill list` changes after each reboot.

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

How can I disable only the bluetooth?