# How do I find Bluetooth in my BIOS?

Tags: 11.10, bluetooth, bios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deactivate Bluetooth on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/deactivate-bluetooth-on-startup)

I want to permanently disable Bluetooth, which I can't seem to do from the OS anymore.

I've read that I need to make the change in my BIOS but I've gone through every setting in the BIOS and I don't see anything that rhymes with Bluetooth.

How do I stop it from launching on startup?

Answer (score 0):

Quite often BIOS has two sets of options. Ordinary and Advanced. To see advanced set You have to use some key combination (in my case it is Ctrl+F1) and then appear much more options. To find out if You have such possibility You have to read Your mainboar manual.
Regards