# How to boot with bluetooth turned off

Tags: bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deactivate Bluetooth on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/deactivate-bluetooth-on-startup)

I don't want to turn off the bluetooth device every time I boot, to save energy and for safety. I want it on on certain occasions during a short time only. So I rather turn it on (it takes 4 seconds) before using it. That should be the natural default configuration. What is going on?