# How to turn off bluetooth?

Tags: 13.04, bluetooth, settings

I want to turn off bluetooth. It seems to be turned off already, but every boot it appears at the panel again.

Here is how it looks at Settings.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This might be useful:
[How to boot with bluetooth turned off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131684/how-to-boot-with-bluetooth-turned-off)

Specifically [the answer by Stepbaer](https://askubuntu.com/a/155886/22949):

> I found a how-to with a clean "workaround":
>
> http://catlingmindswipe.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-disable-bluetooth-on-startup.html
>
> Actually changing /etc/bluetooth/main.conf was enough for me.
>
> ```
> InitiallyPowered = true
> ```

Comment: Tried it on a Toshiba Satellite and it didn't work. Adding `rfkill block bluetooth` to `rc.local` did the job.

Comment: This didn't work on 15.10 either. But I found a solution: http://askubuntu.com/a/696226/34298