# blutooth always on after reboot

Tags: 13.10, bluetooth, system-settings

I don't use bluetooth on my laptop. But my Ubuntu installation doesn't remember my preference to switch-off bluetooth. After rebooting, Blutooth is again switched on.

What is the reason? What is the solution?

Mine is Ubuntu 13.10 on a Dell inspiron laptop

Thanks, KK

Comment: try "rfkill block bluetooth" and check if it works

Comment: Works fine but when I login later, the bluetooth is switched on again :(

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf:

```
sudo gedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

Change `InitiallyPowered = true` to `InitiallyPowered = false`

If that doesn't works, run `sudoedit /etc/rc.local` and add this before line with `exit 0`:

`rfkill block bluetooth`

Source(s):

[How to turn off bluetooth? [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341779/how-to-turn-off-bluetooth)

[How can I deactivate Bluetooth on system startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/how-can-i-deactivate-bluetooth-on-system-startup)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *blueman-applet* has an auto-power setting that automatically enables bluetooth each time the indicator starts. So if you you want Ubuntu to remember your preference open a terminal and type this:

```
$ gsettings set org.blueman.plugins.powermanager auto-power-on false
```

This way you can just disable bluetooth and the OS will remember it and won't automatically re-enable it next time you turn on or reboot your PC.