# Bluetooth keeps turning on

Tags: 12.04, dell, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I deactivate Bluetooth on system startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/how-can-i-deactivate-bluetooth-on-system-startup)

I am running 12.04, and I have absolutely no use for bluetooth right now. I have turned it off, and after i turn it on again, it turns on. I have a dell latitude d830. Thanks for the help in advance

Additional info: it happened again; i turned bluetooth off before i left, restarted the computer, and bluetooth was on.

Even more info: It seems to be doing this in somewhat of a pattern. Sometimes it's on, others its not.