# How to configure bluetooth applet to start OFF or as the last state when logging in?

Tags: login, configuration, bluetooth

Every time I log in, bluetooth is ON and I cannot change this behavior from the bluetooth applet. Is this a bad design or is there a reason why it is like this?

How can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you don't want Bluetooth, you can untick it from the list of applications that run at start-up. How exactly you do it will depend on your desktop environment but in Lubuntu 12.10, here is where you untick it:

[image: Bluetooth]

Comment: It is not that I don't want bluetooth. I would like bluetooth to start in the state, off/on, it had at last shutdown. If that is not possible, I would like it to start in OFF mode but I want to be able to turn it on the moment I need it, like in any normal, not labyrinthine, Operating System.

Comment: I only see a program called `gnome-session-properties`, which is a misleading name because it is only a list of programs to execute at the beginning of a session (GUI session, I suppose, nothing is said)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was to have BT off at startup, it was always powered on when booting. I started from a fresh install of Mint.

As pointed out by posters, there is a file for BT configuration, I edited it:

- `sudo gedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

Two entries to check:

- `RememberPowered = true` (the default value was false on my install.)
- `InitiallyPowered = false` (the default value was true on my install.)

These values allow me to start with BT in the state it had when Ubuntu was terminated.
It seems `RememberPowered` takes precedence on `InitiallyPowered`. Someone more knowledgeable may confirm, or not.

For info, this page is referenced many times when talking about having BT on or off at startup:

[How can I deactivate Bluetooth on system startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/how-can-i-deactivate-bluetooth-on-system-startup)

There is no shortage of ideas it seems...

- edit /etc/rc.local and add rfkill block bluetooth
- edit /etc/rc.local and add echo disable > /proc/acpi/ibm/bluetooth
- edit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and add blacklist btusb
- install BUM: sudo apt-get install bum and run it: sudo bum
- change autostart applis: cd /etc/xdg/autostart/ then sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' *.desktop
- edit /etc/rc.local and add /etc/init.d/bluetooth stop
- disable the service from being started: sudo sh -c then echo 'manual' > /etc/init/bluetooth.override
- use smbios-utils: sudo smbios-wireless-ctl --bt 0
- another one: sudo update-rc.d bluetooth remove
- edit /etc/default/bluetooth and set BLUETOOTH_ENABLED=0

Not sure all this is under control!

Off-site page with some explanations:
- http://catlingmindswipe.blogspot.fr/2012/05/how-to-disable-bluetooth-on-startup.html