# Disabling bluetooth on start not working

Tags: boot, bluetooth

My question is related to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/how-can-i-deactivate-bluetooth-on-system-startup/2568#2568).

I would like to deactivate bluetooth on start up, unfortunately the proposed solution to add:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

to `/etc/rc.local` before `exit 0` does not work on my Acer aspire 1810TZ running Ubuntu 13.10 with an Intel advanced wifilink N-6235.

Neither does the suggested solution for Thinkpad laptops.

What does work is to add:

```
/etc/init.d/bluetooth stop
```

to `/etc/rc.local`, but this disables the bluetooth applet, which I need to enable the bluetooth easily when I want to use bluetooth.

So the question is why doesn't `rfkill block bluetooth` work and how do I make it work again?

Thanks!

Comment: Can tell us if there is more stuff in `/etc/rc.local` except `rfkill block bluetooth`, `exit` and the comments?

Comment: There is one other command `fstrim -v /`, which trims my SSD.

Answer (score 1):

## How to make /etc/rc.local work as expected

Since upstart starts its service asynchronously, it's pretty common that not all services are ready when /etc/rc.local is started. So you need to add `sleep 3` (or another number, you need to find out yourself) at the beginning of you script.

You have to take care that the script isn't interrupted by a program that return's an error. Example: I can switch between two graphics-cards on my laptop (pre hybrid-graphicscard) and depending on which one is turned on I must use a different `/sys/class/backlight/...`-file to set its brightness.
The easiest thing is to set both. But to ensure that the non-existing one doesn't interrupt the `/etc/rc.local`-script I append `|| true` at the end of each command.

So this is how my `rc.local`-script looks right now (sans the comments at the beginning):

```
sleep 3

echo 2 > /sys/class/backlight/sony/brightness || true
echo 2 > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness || true
rfkill block bluetooth

exit 0
```

Comment: I tried adding sleep 3 and sleep 10 at the beginning of the script. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have any effect, bluetooth is still on on boot. How can I discover if the script is being interrupted?

Comment: Try it with a higher number first. Like `sleep 10` or `sleep 15`. You could add `echo "sleep called in /etc/rc.local" >> /var/rc.local.log`, but I don't have access to a Linux computer right now and can't even syntax check that line.