# Ubuntu 13.10 disable bluetooth at startup

Tags: 13.10, bluetooth, startup

what is a easy way to disable blue-tooth at start up with Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/how-can-i-deactivate-bluetooth-on-system-startup). In summary:

- Open the Terminal and enter `sudoedit /etc/rc.local`
- add before the line `exit 0` the line: `rfkill block bluetooth`

Now the Bluetooth should be disabled on startup.