# Make bluetooth disabled by default

Tags: bluetooth

each time I open Ubuntu I have to turnoff bluetooth function from the top panel.
my questions is that is there any method to make it disabled by default?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/67758/8005

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To disable bluetooth service on startup

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

add this line before exit 0

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what to do after adding the last code, In other words how can I save changes?

Comment: Press ctrl+x  and ctrl+s to save your change. This script is running each time you turn on the computer. So this line will turn off the bluetooth

Comment: To save is actually `Ctrl+O` (the letter, not zero)

Comment: You can also use gedit to do this, if you are not comfortable with nano :)

Comment: This doesn't work on Thinkpad X250 + UbuntuStudio 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/155886/416671), what worked for me (in Ubuntu 14.04) was

```
sudo gedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
InitiallyPowered = true     # keep it that way
# add the following:
# start bluetooth on boot?
# compatibility note: if this variable is _not_ found bluetooth will start
BLUETOOTH_ENABLED=0
```

Save the file and reboot.

Comment: This didn't work for me

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Comment: This doesn't work on Thinkpad X250 + UbuntuStudio 16.04 LTS

Comment: You shouldn't downvote it. I just posted what worked FOR ME in the hope it could be useful to someone.