# Ubuntu does not remember Bluetooth setting

Tags: bluetooth, system-settings, autostart

Everytime I start my computer Bluetooth is on. I turn it off. But when I restart my computer it is on again. I don't want to turn it off every time I start my computer. How can I make ubuntu remember the Bluetooth setting from previous session?

These are not options, please suggest something different:

- Never turn off your computer
- Remove Bluetooth hardware
- Permanently turn off Bluetooth
- Recompile your kernel

Comment: What is the result for `ls /etc/default/ | grep tlp`

Comment: The result is: tlp

Comment: Did you see/try my answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deactivate Bluetooth on system startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/how-can-i-deactivate-bluetooth-on-system-startup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Install TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#installation) and [enable the setting](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html)

```
DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth"
```

Comment: As I stated, I don't want to turn it off permanently. I just want it to rememver its last state before shutdown.

Comment: No problem, then use `RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=1`:-) And by the way: DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP is not _permanent_, you may always switch bluetooth in the panel or command line (`bluetooth on|off`).

Comment: This should NOT be the accepted answer. Comments aren't answers and this answer disables bluetooth _permanently_. Maybe editing the answer to include the actual solution.

Answer (score 2):

`gksudo gedit /etc/default/tlp` and go to line 5 which should read

`RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0`

Change it to

`RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=1`

Save, exit gedit, reboot and see if problem is solved

Comment: In my 14.04 there is no `/etc/default/tlp` file, what gives ?

Comment: @heemayl You probably don't have tlp installed

Comment: Which package provides `tlp` ? I can not seem to find it..Also workaround without installing ?

Comment: @heemayl I dont know, try a search for linux tlp, if nothing else you can ask your own question

Comment: TLP is not provided alongside with all linux distros. It would be good to include this advice.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is aware of the latest version of TLP (1.3) and doesn't suggest *disabling the device permanently* as some answers did.

---

After [installing TLP](https://linrunner.de/tlp/installation/index.html), run `sudo editor /etc/tlp.conf` (if, and only if it doesn't exist, try `/etc/defaults/tlp`) and search for the line:

`#RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0`

Change it to:

`RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=1`

Reboot and test it.

- Hint: if your terminal editor is Nano, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, `RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP` (or a part of it) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to quickly find the line. Edit it and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close Nano.

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/bluetooth/main.conf, uncomment (remove the '#') the line that has the option AutoEnable and set it to false.

```
# AutoEnable defines option to enable all controllers when they are found.
# This includes adapters present on start as well as adapters that are plugg
# in later on. Defaults to 'true'.
AutoEnable=false
```

Refer to the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth#Default_adapter_power_state) for more info.

Edit: This will make the Bluetooth be turned off on startup. It will not remember the state from last boot.