# How can I set bluetooth off as default?

Tags: boot, bluetooth, settings

Whenever I turn my bluetooth off from the settings menu, it's back on after reboot. I know this has already been asked but I've tried all answers that have been provided and nothing seems to work.

The most popular suggestion is: Run `sudoedit /etc/rc.local` and add this before line with exit 0:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

When I do this, an empty file opens up and it's not even `rc.local` if I'm correct. (see screenshot).
I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

[image: Screenshot]

If I run `ls -l /etc/rc.local` this comes up:

[image: Screenshot2]

If I run: `sudo rfkill list all`:

[image: Screenshot3]

I've tried everything in this link except installing BUM: [How can I deactivate Bluetooth on system startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/how-can-i-deactivate-bluetooth-on-system-startup)

Comment: Well, what's the link to the other suggestions you tried ? Yes, the file in screenshot is a temp file, which is odd. Did you run `sudoedit /etc/rc.local` or did it differ somehow ? Does `ls -l /etc/rc.local` suggests it's a symlink ?

Comment: Also, `sudo rfkill list all`  output would be nice to add

Comment: "When I do this, an empty file opens up and it's not even rc.local if I'm correct. "  Yes it is. Custom method in Linux: editing a file in use is bad practice,  so a file in /tmp/ is created and mv to the place it needs to be. Next: you did not find anything on blacklisting the bt module?! I find that odd ;)

Comment: I've tried everything in this link except installing BUM: https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/how-can-i-deactivate-bluetooth-on-system-startup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu does not remember Bluetooth setting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676360/ubuntu-does-not-remember-bluetooth-setting)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deactivate Bluetooth on system startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/how-can-i-deactivate-bluetooth-on-system-startup)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've tested this and it's persistent across reboots.

Click the bluetooth logo between the keyboard and battery icons on the system tray. Then click the "Bluetooth ON" selection and it changes to "Bluetooth OFF":

[image: bluetooth off.gif]

---

After comments I discovered that Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome interface doesn't work like Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity interface.

The solution is to edit `/etc/default/tlp` and find:

```
# Radio devices to disable on startup: bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
# Separate multiple devices with spaces.
#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth wifi wwan"
```

Edit the last line to read:

```
DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth"
```

Comment: I'm gonna assume you really did think I haven't tried the most basic solution.
When I do this, the bluetooth is back on after reboot.

Comment: @LucyC I just noticed from your screenshots you don't even have the bluetooth icon in systray. Furthermore you are using Gnome interface and not Unity 16.04 interface like me. Are you using Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. My bluetooth icon can be found in the dropdown settings menu as shown here:  [https://ibb.co/h5pmaJ]

Comment: @LucyC I'll reboot using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with default Gnome interface and check it out.

Comment: @LucyC After rebooting into Ubuntu 18.40 I was shocked to learn under the Gnome interface the setting isn't retained. On searching for a solution I found a duplicate question with an accepted answer so voted to close your question as a duplicate. So now I'll boot back into 16.04 which just works :)

Comment: As I stated in my question, I've tried all other solutions given in other posts and they won't work for me- That's why I decided to create my own post :/

Comment: Try this solution to remove bluetooth applet from startup applications. I just started the Sherlock Holmes movie and don't feel like rebooting into Ubuntu 18.40 hell again :p https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/turn-off-bluetooth-by-default/12979

Comment: I took me a while to realize I hadn't edited the tlp configurations files correctly. I had written #DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth". Removing the # did the trick. THANK YOU!
btw, why "ubuntu 18.04 hell". I'm a beginner to this so may be, if you could explain to me why I shouldn't be running it, it would be awesome. Can we chat?

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 19.10 on a Thinkpad.

Comment: In 2023, this file is `/etc/tlp.conf` OS: Devuan 5

Comment: @vrgovinda **"Version 5 of systemd-free Debian remix Devuan"** is severely off-topic here in ***Ask Ubuntu***. That said, I hope it serves you well.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I agree with you. Isn't it the same in Ubuntu as well?

Comment: @vrgovinda I don't know. I believe Ubuntu is exclusively `systemd` these days and the old init days are history. Either way only a software engineered that scoured source code and compared the OS could tell you if they are the same.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I have a suggession. I think most of the people will try to make the devices to remember the state of the previous shutdown. Thus if wifi/bluetooth is turned off/on before the previous shutdown, then after rebooting, wifi/bluetooth remains off/on according the previous state.

To do this, go to the file `/etc/default/tlp` and search for the line

> RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0

This is set as "0" by default, which means that remembering the state of radio is disabled by default. To make it remember the previous state, replace "0" with "1".
If you set this as "1", the lines after that will not be read by the system.

If you specifically wants to set some radio to be on or off at start up, then follow the lines

> #DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth wifi wwan"

and

> #DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth wifi wwan"

and remove the '#' to activate any of those line. And you can choose between bluetooth/wifi/wwan or all of them.

Do as you need.

Answer (score 6):

I work under Xubuntu 18.04. Here is a solution that finally worked for me.

1. First, I edited the file `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` (under `sudo` mode enabled). At the very end of the file, I changed the line `AutoEnable=true` to `AutoEnable=false`
2. Second, I went to the main menu, then picked `Settings > Session and Startup`. In the `Applications autostart` section I disabled `Blueman applet` (see line 2 in the picture below).

[image: Blueman applet disabled in 'Session and Startup']

3. After reboot, the `Blueman applet` icon is no longer visible in the system tray but if you enter `rfkill list all` in the terminal, you see the following:

`1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no`

Which means that the Bluetooth is now off. The key to the problem, it seems, is ridiculously simple. Any attempt to switch the `Blueman applet` on also switches on the Bluetooth no matter what happened before. So, no `Blueman applet`, no more Bluetooth on boot. At least, for me.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.10 - step 1 was totally enough for me (Blueman does not seem to be installed) :)

Comment: See the blueman [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/blueman/+bug/1763221)

Comment: The first option works perfectly in Ubuntu 18,04.4 LTS. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

With ubuntu 18.04 gnome this worked for me:

```
sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service
```

then after reboot try to check:

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
```

And if you want to enable it again:

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
```

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 19.10 on a Thinkpad.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.10 on Dell XPS

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround for your case...

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 18.04, in my case I just click on "MENU/Preferences/Startup Applications".
A window called "Startup Applications Preferences" pops up. Find the entry called "Blueman Applet" and remove the tick/tag from it so that it becomes disabled (grayed out). As a result, all the applications related with Bluetooth will not load the next time(s) you boot up your system.

The annoying part is that you will have to reverse this procedure and reboot to get bluetooth back to work in case you need it.

Hope this helps
JaMedSyS

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu 18.04. touching files like turn it off if you use blueman as a bluetooth application.
For this I go to this location with a file browser executed with superuser permissions:

```
/usr/bin/
```

and I edit the file called:

```
"Blueman-applet"
```

Within this file there is written a line that says:

```
self.Plugins.Run(“on_manager_state_changed”, True)
```

You just have to change true to false and it would stay like this:

```
self.Plugins.Run ("on_manager_state_changed", False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 "bionic" with KDE (so kubuntu 18.04.2) and all I did was issue:

**`sudo rfkill block bluetooth`**

It does not enable itself after a reboot. To enable, all I do is go into bluetooth settings and tick the checkbox "Enable Bluetooth Integration".