# Bluetooth turns on after booting into Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

My HP laptop's Bluetooth turns ON every time I start the machine, even if I had turned it OFF in the previous session.

How do I make my changes to the Bluetooth persist even after shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/677201/746389) using **tlp** package.

Installation:`sudo apt install tlp`

Then edit the file in `/etc/default/tlp` with sudo privileges.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/tlp
```

On line 5 you will see:

```
RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0
```

change this value to 1 i.e.:

`RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=`**1**