# Best way to deactivate Bluetooth on system startup? (with systemd and not upstart)

Tags: 15.10, bluetooth, upstart, systemd

What is the best way to deactivate Bluetooth for every startup with systemd?
There are a lot of examples, but all of them work with upstart and rc.local.

With Ubuntu 15.10 rc.local is disabled by default. I think it's for a reason, or isn't it?

So how can I deactivate the Bluetooth target/service correctly without the rc.local script?

Maybe reactivate rc.local an add the line "rfkill block bluetooth" is the proper way?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, stop the service:

```
sudo systemctl stop bluetooth.service
```

Then, disable it:

```
sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service
```

Check:

```
systemctl status bluetooth.service
```

Comment: that was exactly what i am searching for! thanks

Comment: no problem, u'r welcome ;)

Comment: @IvanTemchenko great answer. I think you should write it also [on this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/67758/29595). It collects already a lot of old and new procedures, and this is missing.

Comment: Thank you, I've been looking for this solution for a few weeks, this is the way to do it on ubuntu 16.10 (systemd)

Comment: This is the way to go

Answer (score 11):

Most of the methods above totally disable bluetooth, while probably many users just want their OS to remember their preference. The problem is that blueman-applet has an auto-power-on setting that automatically enables bluetooth each time the indicator starts. So if you you want Ubuntu to remember your preference open a terminal and type this:

```
$ gsettings set org.blueman.plugins.powermanager auto-power-on false
```

This way you can just disable bluetooth and the OS will remember it and won't automatically re-enable it next time you turn on or reboot your PC.

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I needed! A way to make it stop being on everytime, but leave it easy re-enable it.

Answer (score 4):

To disable it so it never tries to restart (*as other apps may be trying to start it after you've disabled it and will show up with errors in the journal log*) after stopping and disabling, you can `sudo systemctl mask dbus-org.bluez.service`, this points the symlink to /dev/null. To restore it `sudo systemctl unmask dbus-org.bluez.service` in systemd.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW54_1.1.1/com.ibm.kvm.v111.admin/hpssdisabling.htm

Comment: I gave +1 because my system kept showing errors at startup and I could not get them to stop, until I found this advice.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the bluetooth configuration file and set AutoEnable to false to disable bluetooth on boot.

`sudo gedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

At the end of the file

`AutoEnable=false`