# Dell Inspiron 7567 randomly disconnecting from network

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.04, mate

I recently purchased a Dell Inspiron 7567, and added a dual boot of Ubuntu Mate, version 17.04.

For some reason, my wireless seems to randomly disconnect every so often. I haven't noticed any new icons on the wireless icon in the top of the screen.

It will usually happen whenever I am web browsing, and I will be forced to close the tab and re-open in order to load a page. 
It will also often happen when I am trying to download something. It will be downloading at a steady 1.5 MB/ps or so, and then slowly ramp down to 0 B/s.

This issue appears both when I am using Firefox which comes pre-installed, as well as Google Chrome.

This issue does not appear when I use Windows 10.

My specs:

- i5-7300HQ
- 8GB RAM
- GTX 1050

Output of `sudo lshw -class network`:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface

       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller

       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.

       physical id: 0

       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: d4:81:d7:95:df:36
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation

       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s

       resources: irq:125 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d5104000-d5104fff memory:d5100000-d5103fff

  *-network

       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 79
       serial: 70:1c:e7:d9:17:37
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.10.0-32-generic firmware=22.391740.0 ip=192.168.1.83 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:128 memory:d5000000-d5001fff ~
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out simply updating from the old 4.10.something kernel which Ubuntu comes with to either 4.12 or 4.13 fixes the issue. For some reason 4.11 refused to properly install, but that doesn't really matter since its outdated anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an Inspiron N7110. After doing significant digging, I think I found the culprit. It's the 2-in-1 Network/Bluetooth card. While I can't promise its going to work, after making these changes it functions perfectly now.

> First, stop the service:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl stop bluetooth.service
> ```
>
> Then disable it:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service
> ```
>
> Check:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
> ```

Courtesy of [Ivan Temchenko](https://askubuntu.com/users/338095/ivan-temchenko) found here: [Best way to deactivate Bluetooth on system startup? (with systemd and not upstart)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744640/best-way-to-deactivate-bluetooth-on-system-startup-with-systemd-and-not-upstar)