# Bluetooth is always turned on when on startup. How do I fix this problem?

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, startup, automount

A few days ago I turned on Bluetooth on my laptop and then turned it off.

Now I see every time  I start the laptop, I see the Bluetooth is turned on and I should turn it off manually and sometimes I forget.

How should I fix this problem? (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: What files are in `~/.config/autostart` directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deactivate Bluetooth on system startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/how-can-i-deactivate-bluetooth-on-system-startup)

Comment: You can try `tlp`

Answer (score 1):

There are more technical solutions - none of which worked for me, at least, not without killing the manager or the adapter - so, after a couple of hours going around in circles, I gave in and made a simple "fix" - I wanted to keep the icon, essentially, but have bluetooth switched off at start up.

1. Create a file, call it sbo.sh, the contents of which should be:
   `#!/bin/bash`
   `sleep 1`
   `rfkill block bluetooth`
2. I saved this in /opt (any user space would do), then made sure I was owner:
   `sudo chown myname:myname /opt/sbo.sh`
   ...and that it was executable:
   `sudo chmod u+x /opt/sbo.sh`
3. Then I opened "Startup Applications Preferences"
   Clicked on "Add" then entered the following details:
   Name: `Switch Bluetooth Off`
   Command: `/opt/sbo.sh`
   Comment: `Switch off bluetooth but keep icon at start`

Seems to work.  The one second pause ("`sleep 1`" in step 1) is important... it's enough of a lag for the device to become enabled.  Doubtless not the most elegant work around, but after a couple of hours twiddling with things (like `/etc/rc.local`, systemd, etc.) to no avail... it's something that works.