# How to disable bluetooth on startup Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: boot, bluetooth, 18.10

How to disable bluetooth automatic turn on in Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: when you first time turnoff the bluetooth and shutdown, then turn on the system.. is it turning the bluetooth on at startup?

Comment: in my fresh install of Ubuntu 18.10, before shutting down, what is its state, i.e on or off.. after reboot it is in the same state when shutting down.

Comment: Bluetooth always turns on automatically when I power on my system, when I turn bluetooth off and reboot, my system has bluetooth turned on when I unlock.

Comment: is your laptop having physical key to turn bluetooth on or off and in BIOS settings are there anything related to it?

Comment: The question has been asked about previous Ubuntu versions, do none of those answers work?  https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bbluetooth%5Ddisable+start

Comment: PRATAP No my computer doesn't have a bluetooth key and there is no bluetooth options in the BIOS.

Comment: Jeremy31 No those don't work, they are for older versions of ubuntu my versions doesn't have those files in those directories.

Comment: Do you have anything (mouse, radio dongle) plugged in the USB ports? If yes, does bluetooth also start on startup when you turn it off, unplug the USB stuff and reboot?

Comment: sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service   .... see duplicate question I linked to in above comment ... and yes this works on 18.10 too

Answer (score 1):

[This AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/941953/934362) was the one that do it for me.

It uses `systemctl` to turn off the `bluetooth.service`:

> to deactivate bluetooth on startup issue this
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service
> ```

Comment: Just to add, you can reference and quote any answers you like in your answer but DO NOT post an answer that is just a link to another. Make it your own, use your own word and just quote the relevant part of the other answer. This "There is a solution in this post [LINK]", is not an acceptable answer.