# Bluetooth Stays On

Tags: boot, 18.04, bluetooth

I mostly keep my bluetooth off on my laptop. Whenever I reboot my laptop it also is on. Im running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on a Lenovo E41-15 with stock hardware and an extra 120gb SSD as boot drive.

Comment: Here's a good answer that explains how to do it https://askubuntu.com/a/2568/300619

Answer (score 0, accepted):

18.04+ users who don't naturally have a `/etc/rc.local`, you'll need to create one and make it executable. To make things slightly easier, you can just paste the following command into a terminal:

```
sudo install -b -m 755 /dev/stdin /etc/rc.local << EOF
#!/bin/sh
rfkill block bluetooth
exit 0
EOF
```

Run sudoedit `/etc/rc.local` and add this before line with exit 0:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

You should still be able to enable Bluetooth through the top bar applet.

This should work for most systems but it looks like there are a few bugs lurking in the kernel's ACPI for Thinkpads. If you're on a Thinkpad, add the following to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
echo disable > /proc/acpi/ibm/bluetooth
```

[[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/2568/300619)]

Comment: Instead of `rc.local` it is done by `systemctl disable bluetooth`

Comment: BTW, for anyone reading, the correct command would be `systemctl disable bluetooth` ... @Pilot6 made a lil typo in there...

Comment: @Pilot6 after authenticating, it says permission denied. I enter the correct password though!