# I want to turn off "Blutooth" HP-EliteBook-Folio-9480m TO save power consume

Tags: networking, bluetooth, battery

When I give this command `sudo service bluetooth status`, it gives this output:

```
[sudo] password for v: 
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor prese>
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
lines 1-4/4 (END)
```

And `rfkill` gives this output:

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hci0     blocked unblocked
```

I am trying to understand if my bluetooth is:

- turned on or off
- running & consuming battery
- consuming power

How can I turn it off?

Comment: If you are using a modern version of Ubuntu Desktop, then you can usually *see* this by clocking the little battery icon in the upper-right corner of your screen. This will show you whether your WiFi is on and connected, if your Bluetooth is on, and other basic things. If you do not have this view, could you [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu you're running?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** If you're interested in turning Bluetooth off at startup, there's a good discussion about how to do that here: https://askubuntu.com/q/67758/32664. For me, this is a good solution, as I rarely use BT on my laptop, so when I do need it, I can turn it on rather than have it always on.